# React native to app store missing required arguments

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to prepare my app to be uploaded to the app store but when I type the following command

react-native bundle --minify

I get the error

entry-file, bundle-output

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to supply the entry file and output file as parameters. Try this:

```
react-native bundle --minify --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output main.jsbundle
```